# View dentro de uma área como default no MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

Como posso fazer para que uma view que esta dentro de uma área seja a default quando rodar a aplicação?

Erro que eu estou recebendo:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Minha estrutura:

[image: Minha estrutura:]

Meu arquivo RouteConfig

> Isso que eu fiz abaixo não funcionou.

```
namespace WebApplication1
{
    public class RouteConfig
    {
        public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
        {
            routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");
            routes.MapRoute(
                name: "Default",
                url: "{area}/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
                defaults: new { area = "Administracao", controller = "Usuarios", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
            );
        }
    }
}
```

Obrigado

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A rota está ok. O grande problema aqui está no *View Engine*, que não é algo simples de resolver. [Vou traduzir esta resposta do SO gringo](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2172349/1314276):

Primeiro você precisa criar um *View Engine* que olhe sobre as áreas do seu projeto. Em meus projetos, uso o *namespace* `MeuProjeto.Infrastructure.ViewEngines`:

## BaseAreaAwareViewEngine.cs

```
public abstract class BaseAreaAwareViewEngine : VirtualPathProviderViewEngine
{
    private static readonly string[] EmptyLocations = { };

    public override ViewEngineResult FindView(
        ControllerContext controllerContext, string viewName,
        string masterName, bool useCache)
    {
        if (controllerContext == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException("controllerContext");
        }
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(viewName))
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException(viewName,
                "Value cannot be null or empty.");
        }

        string area = getArea(controllerContext);
        return FindAreaView(controllerContext, area, viewName,
            masterName, useCache);
    }

    public override ViewEngineResult FindPartialView(
        ControllerContext controllerContext, string partialViewName,
        bool useCache)
    {
        if (controllerContext == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException("controllerContext");
        }
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(partialViewName))
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException(partialViewName,
                "Value cannot be null or empty.");
        }

        string area = getArea(controllerContext);
        return FindAreaPartialView(controllerContext, area,
            partialViewName, useCache);
    }

    protected virtual ViewEngineResult FindAreaView(
        ControllerContext controllerContext, string areaName, string viewName,
        string masterName, bool useCache)
    {
        string controllerName =
            controllerContext.RouteData.GetRequiredString("controller");
        string[] searchedViewPaths;
        string viewPath = GetPath(controllerContext, ViewLocationFormats,
            "ViewLocationFormats", viewName, controllerName, areaName, "View",
            useCache, out searchedViewPaths);
        string[] searchedMasterPaths;
        string masterPath = GetPath(controllerContext, MasterLocationFormats,
            "MasterLocationFormats", masterName, controllerName, areaName,
            "Master", useCache, out searchedMasterPaths);
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(viewPath) &&
            (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(masterPath) || 
              string.IsNullOrEmpty(masterName)))
        {
            return new ViewEngineResult(CreateView(controllerContext, viewPath,
                masterPath), this);
        }
        return new ViewEngineResult(
            searchedViewPaths.Union<string>(searchedMasterPaths));
    }

    protected virtual ViewEngineResult FindAreaPartialView(
        ControllerContext controllerContext, string areaName,
        string viewName, bool useCache)
    {
        string controllerName =
            controllerContext.RouteData.GetRequiredString("controller");
        string[] searchedViewPaths;
        string partialViewPath = GetPath(controllerContext,
            ViewLocationFormats, "PartialViewLocationFormats", viewName,
            controllerName, areaName, "Partial", useCache,
            out searchedViewPaths);
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(partialViewPath))
        {
            return new ViewEngineResult(CreatePartialView(controllerContext,
                partialViewPath), this);
        }
        return new ViewEngineResult(searchedViewPaths);
    }

    protected string CreateCacheKey(string prefix, string name,
        string controller, string area)
    {
        return string.Format(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture,
            ":ViewCacheEntry:{0}:{1}:{2}:{3}:{4}:",
            base.GetType().AssemblyQualifiedName,
            prefix, name, controller, area);
    }

    protected string GetPath(ControllerContext controllerContext,
        string[] locations, string locationsPropertyName, string name,
        string controllerName, string areaName, string cacheKeyPrefix,
        bool useCache, out string[] searchedLocations)
    {
        searchedLocations = EmptyLocations;
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(name))
        {
            return string.Empty;
        }
        if ((locations == null) || (locations.Length == 0))
        {
            throw new InvalidOperationException(string.Format("The property " +
                "'{0}' cannot be null or empty.", locationsPropertyName));
        }
        bool isSpecificPath = IsSpecificPath(name);
        string key = CreateCacheKey(cacheKeyPrefix, name,
            isSpecificPath ? string.Empty : controllerName,
            isSpecificPath ? string.Empty : areaName);
        if (useCache)
        {
            string viewLocation = ViewLocationCache.GetViewLocation(
                controllerContext.HttpContext, key);
            if (viewLocation != null)
            {
                return viewLocation;
            }
        }
        if (!isSpecificPath)
        {
            return GetPathFromGeneralName(controllerContext, locations, name,
                controllerName, areaName, key, ref searchedLocations);
        }
        return GetPathFromSpecificName(controllerContext, name, key,
            ref searchedLocations);
    }

    protected string GetPathFromGeneralName(ControllerContext controllerContext,
        string[] locations, string name, string controllerName,
        string areaName, string cacheKey, ref string[] searchedLocations)
    {
        string virtualPath = string.Empty;
        searchedLocations = new string[locations.Length];
        for (int i = 0; i < locations.Length; i++)
        {
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(areaName) && locations[i].Contains("{2}"))
            {
                continue;
            }
            string testPath = string.Format(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture,
                locations[i], name, controllerName, areaName);
            if (FileExists(controllerContext, testPath))
            {
                searchedLocations = EmptyLocations;
                virtualPath = testPath;
                ViewLocationCache.InsertViewLocation(
                    controllerContext.HttpContext, cacheKey, virtualPath);
                return virtualPath;
            }
            searchedLocations[i] = testPath;
        }
        return virtualPath;
    }

    protected string GetPathFromSpecificName(
        ControllerContext controllerContext, string name, string cacheKey,
        ref string[] searchedLocations)
    {
        string virtualPath = name;
        if (!FileExists(controllerContext, name))
        {
            virtualPath = string.Empty;
            searchedLocations = new string[] { name };
        }
        ViewLocationCache.InsertViewLocation(controllerContext.HttpContext,
            cacheKey, virtualPath);
        return virtualPath;
    }


    protected string getArea(ControllerContext controllerContext)
    {
        // First try to get area from a RouteValue override, like one specified in the Defaults arg to a Route.
        object areaO;
        controllerContext.RouteData.Values.TryGetValue("area", out areaO);

        // If not specified, try to get it from the Controller's namespace
        if (areaO != null)
            return (string)areaO;

        string namespa = controllerContext.Controller.GetType().Namespace;
        int areaStart = namespa.IndexOf("Areas.");
        if (areaStart == -1)
            return null;

        areaStart += 6;
        int areaEnd = namespa.IndexOf('.', areaStart + 1);
        string area = namespa.Substring(areaStart, areaEnd - areaStart);
        return area;
    }

    protected static bool IsSpecificPath(string name)
    {
        char ch = name[0];
        if (ch != '~')
        {
            return (ch == '/');
        }
        return true;
    }
}
```

Como a classe é abstrata, você precisará também criar a classe que deriva `BaseAreaAwareViewEngine`:

## AreaAwareViewEngine.cs

```
public class AreaAwareViewEngine : BaseAreaAwareViewEngine
{
    public AreaAwareViewEngine()
    {
        MasterLocationFormats = new string[]
        {
            "~/Areas/{2}/Views/{1}/{0}.master",
            "~/Areas/{2}/Views/{1}/{0}.cshtml",
            "~/Areas/{2}/Views/Shared/{0}.master",
            "~/Areas/{2}/Views/Shared/{0}.cshtml",
            "~/Views/{1}/{0}.master",
            "~/Views/{1}/{0}.cshtml",
            "~/Views/Shared/{0}.master"
            "~/Views/Shared/{0}.cshtml"
        };
        ViewLocationFormats = new string[]
        {
            "~/Areas/{2}/Views/{1}/{0}.aspx",
            "~/Areas/{2}/Views/{1}/{0}.ascx",
            "~/Areas/{2}/Views/{1}/{0}.cshtml",
            "~/Areas/{2}/Views/Shared/{0}.aspx",
            "~/Areas/{2}/Views/Shared/{0}.ascx",
            "~/Areas/{2}/Views/Shared/{0}.cshtml",
            "~/Views/{1}/{0}.aspx",
            "~/Views/{1}/{0}.ascx",
            "~/Views/{1}/{0}.cshtml",
            "~/Views/Shared/{0}.aspx"
            "~/Views/Shared/{0}.ascx"
            "~/Views/Shared/{0}.cshtml"
        };
        PartialViewLocationFormats = ViewLocationFormats;
    }

    protected override IView CreatePartialView(
        ControllerContext controllerContext, string partialPath)
    {
        if (partialPath.EndsWith(".cshtml"))
            return new System.Web.Mvc.RazorView(controllerContext, partialPath, null, false, null);
        else
            return new WebFormView(controllerContext, partialPath);
    }

    protected override IView CreateView(ControllerContext controllerContext,
        string viewPath, string masterPath)
    {
        if (viewPath.EndsWith(".cshtml"))
            return new RazorView(controllerContext, viewPath, masterPath, false, null);
        else
            return new WebFormView(controllerContext, viewPath, masterPath);
    }
}
```

Note que `MasterLocationFormats` muda a prioridade de pesquisa do *View Engine* para primeiro olhar as áreas.

```
        MasterLocationFormats = new string[]
        {
            "~/Areas/{2}/Views/{1}/{0}.master",
            "~/Areas/{2}/Views/{1}/{0}.cshtml",
            "~/Areas/{2}/Views/Shared/{0}.master",
            "~/Areas/{2}/Views/Shared/{0}.cshtml",
            "~/Views/{1}/{0}.master",
            "~/Views/{1}/{0}.cshtml",
            "~/Views/Shared/{0}.master"
            "~/Views/Shared/{0}.cshtml"
        };
```

Agora você precisará registrar o *View Engine* no `Global.asax.cs`:

## Global.asax.cs

```
protected void Application_Start()
{
    RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
    ViewEngines.Engines.Clear();
    ViewEngines.Engines.Add(new AreaAwareViewEngine());
}
```

Apenas isso já é suficiente para funcionar. A resposta detalha mais algumas coisas, mas grosso modo, é isto.

Comment: Obrigado, embora eu não tenha conseguido entender quase nada de como isso funciona ele funcionou. Eu tinha visto este post no SO de fora mas como meu inglês é fraco eu não consegui entender, ainda mais que é difícil de acreditar que para fazer algo tão simples precisa de tantas linhas de código.

Comment: É verdade. A questão das áreas, a meu ver, não foi bem feita no ASP.NET MVC. Tanto que estão para abandonar o conceito na próxima versão do produto.

Comment: Acho que vou fazer isso também, abandonar elas e deixar os controles, models e views misturados dentro de suas pastas da raiz.